# extract headers (h1) from html document

Tags: c++, html, css, tidy

I want to use tidypp based on tidylib, executing the following example works fine, but the following example extract hrefs, witch means tag = "tidytag_A" and attribute ="href", I have no idea how can I extract tags like `<h1>`, `<p>`, ...

[The example here](https://code.google.com/p/tidypp/wiki/Example01)

I tried to lookout in tidylib sources and i cant find a method to do this,any suggestions please.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What isn't working and how should it be working? What have you tried so far (provide code examples). Do can you create a fiddle to show the issue?

Comment: @badAdviceGuy i tryed the code in the example provided in the post , this code returns a list of links; i want a list of <h1> in the html document

Comment: for my dumphrefs function:
void dumphrefs(tidypp::node &node, std::list<std::string> *dst)
{
    
    for (tidypp::node child = node.child(); child.valid(); child = child.next())
    {
        bool isheader = node.ish1; // obtain tag id to check if it's a h1

        
        if (isheader)
        {
            //code to add the content of <h1> to the list;
        }

        // walk all the children of each children recursively
        dumphrefs(child, dst);
    }
}

Comment: sorry  i  dont know how to write code in comment

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your basic block of code that tries to detect the `<h1>`? We can't really help you with code that you're hiding from us.